# How to authenticate at MongoDB Atlas API using digest authentication?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, authentication, digest-authentication, mongodb-atlas

I want to get a list of projects in MongoDB using its API "https://cloud.mongodb.com/api/atlas/v1.0/groups" but every time I get error as "401 You are not authorized for this resource".

According to the [docs](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/api/project-get-all/) digest authentication is used.

Seems like I am passing the Private_key and Public_key in the wrong way.

Below is my request object

```
{
url: 'https://cloud.mongodb.com/api/atlas/v1.0/groups',
method: 'GET',
headers: {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
},
auth: {
  user: 'Public_Key',
  pass: 'Private_key'
  }
}
```

Can anyone please help me with this.

Comment: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/api/project-get-all/
The above API link of MongoDB says use Private_key and Public_key for authentication but still confused am I using it in the right way.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I reworded the question a little bit to make it clearer and also added the link. So it's digest authentication. I can't answer it right away, but there's an  [example on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication#Example_with_explanation). You get a `nonce` and some other values in the 401 response from the server and need to calculate your response value using MD5 hashing.

Comment: you can also click on the `digest authentication` tag to see other question and anwers, some also contains code examples which might help to get an idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are missing is the key "sendImmediately". You need to send it in your auth object as follows :

```
   request({
       method: 'GET',
       auth: {
       "user": Public_Key,
       "pass": Private_key,
       "sendImmediately": false
   },
       url: 'https://cloud.mongodb.com/api/atlas/v1.0?pretty=true'
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests 
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
auth= HTTPDigestAuth(secrets['AtlasPublicKey'], secrets['AtlasPrivateKey'])
```

This should work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.